# PyLint AttributeError

Tags: python, pylint, linter

Receving this error while running `pylint` on my py file

```
AttributeError: 'Import' object has no attribute 'infer_name_module'
```

Full trace:

```
$ pylint some_file.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "\lib\runpy.py", line 197, in _run_module_as_main
    return _run_code(code, main_globals, None,
  File "\lib\runpy.py", line 87, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "\Scripts\pylint.exe\__main__.py", line 7, in <module>
  File "\lib\site-packages\pylint\__init__.py", line 19, in run_pylint
    Run(sys.argv[1:])
  File "\lib\site-packages\pylint\lint.py", line 1394, in __init__
    linter.check(args)
  File "\lib\site-packages\pylint\lint.py", line 801, in check
    self._do_check(files_or_modules)
  File "\lib\site-packages\pylint\lint.py", line 938, in _do_check
    self.check_astroid_module(ast_node, walker, rawcheckers, tokencheckers)
  File "\lib\site-packages\pylint\lint.py", line 1018, in check_astroid_module
    walker.walk(ast_node)
  File "\lib\site-packages\pylint\utils.py", line 1159, in walk
    self.walk(child)
  File "\lib\site-packages\pylint\utils.py", line 1156, in walk
    cb(astroid)
  File "\lib\site-packages\pylint\checkers\variables.py", line 1331, in visit_import
    module = next(node.infer_name_module(parts[0]))
AttributeError: 'Import' object has no attribute 'infer_name_module'
```

Not sure for root cause.

```
pylint version 2.12.2
```

Comment: Paste the line where the error occurs. But just a guess - why is the `I` capital in Import?

Comment: IDK edit the full trace

Comment: Judging by https://bugs.launchpad.net/networking-midonet/+bug/1818384, could you have mismatched versions of `pylint` and some of its dependencies, eg. `astroid`?

Comment: both latest
pylint 2.12.2
astroid 2.9.3

Answer (score 0):

I'm a pylint maintainer. It's a bug in pylint, could you [open an issue](https://github.com/PyCQA/pylint/issues/new?assignees=&labels=bug%2Cneeds+triage&template=BUG-REPORT.yml), please ? We'd need the code that create the crash if possible.

Edit : it was a bug in an old version of pylint 2.0.2, not 2.12.2

Comment: https://github.com/PyCQA/pylint/issues/5759